# How to make a button click trigger a parent anchor click?

Tags: jquery, button, onclick

```
<a href="www.google.com">
  <span>Some text</span>
  <button class="triggeranchorclick"/>
</a>
```

Using jQuery, how could you cause a click of the button to trigger the link to be clicked - i.e. the user ends up getting redirected to Google.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, why do u wanna do this, 'cause you're wrapping the `<button>` with an `<a>` tag. so you don't need to write extra bit of code for doing this

Anyway here's my technique,

```
$(function () {
    $('.triggeranchorclick').bind('click', function (e) {
        window.location.href = $(this).parent('a').attr('href');
    });
});
```

### [Test it here](http://jsbin.com/aduqu3)